# ArrayList of integer arrays

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm trying to write a simple game where an enemy chases the player on a grid. I'm using the simple algorithm for pathfinding from the Wikipedia page on pathfinding. This involves creating two lists with each list item containing 3 integers. Here's test code I'm trying out to build and display such a list.

When I run the following code, it prints out the same numbers for each array in the ArrayList. Why does it do this?

```
public class ListTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Integer[]> list = new ArrayList<Integer[]>(); 
    Integer[] point = new Integer[3];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            point[j] = (int)(Math.random() * 10);
        }            

        //Doesn't this line add filled Integer[] point to the 
        //end of ArrayList list?
        list.add(point);      

        //Added this line to confirm that Integer[] point is actually 
        //being filled with 3 random ints.
        System.out.println(point[0] + "," + point[1] + "," + point[2]);
    }
    System.out.println();

    //My current understanding is that this section should step through 
    //ArrayList list and retrieve each Integer[] point added above. It runs, but only 
    //the values of the last Integer[] point from above are displayed 10 times.
    Iterator it = list.iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        point = (Integer[])it.next();  
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            System.out.print(point[i] + ",");
        } 
            System.out.println(); 
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens when you compile this code?

Comment: It will run (I'm writing in Netbeans IDE), but it prints the same random numbers, say 9,9,2 ten times.

Comment: Did your original code using `int[]`s do the same thing?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First of all, several of the other answers are misleading and/or incorrect. Note that an array is an object. So you can use them as elements in a list, no matter whether the arrays themselves contain primitive types or object references.

Next, declaring a variable as `List<int[]> list` is preferred over declaring it as `ArrayList<int[]>`. This allows you to easily change the `List` to a `LinkedList` or some other implementation without breaking the rest of your code because it is guaranteed to use only methods available in the `List` interface. For more information, you should research "programming to the interface."

Now to answer your real question, which was only added as a comment. Let's look at a few lines of your code:

```
Integer[] point = new Integer[3];
```

This line creates an array of `Integer`s, obviously.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        point[j] = (int)(Math.random() * 10);
    }            

    //Doesn't this line add filled Integer[] point to the 
    //end of ArrayList list?
    list.add(point);
    //...
}
```

Here you assign values to the elements of the array and then add a **reference** to the array to your `List`. Each time the loop iterates, you assign new values **to the same array** and add **another reference to the same array** to the `List`. This means that the `List` has 10 references **to the same array** which has been repeatedly written over.

Iterator it = list.iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        point = (Integer[])it.next();
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            System.out.print(point[i] + ",");
        } 
            System.out.println(); 
        } 
    }

Now this loop prints out the **same array** 10 times. The values in the array are the last ones set at the end of the previous loop.

To fix the problem, you simply need to be sure to create 10 **different** arrays.

One last issue: If you declare `it` as `Iterator<Integer[]> it` (or `Iterator<int[]> it`), you do not need to cast the return value of `it.next()`. In fact this is preferred because it is type-safe.

Finally, I want to ask what the `int`s in each array represent? You might want to revisit your program design and create a class that holds these three `int`s, either as an array or as three member variables.

Comment: Wow, thanks so much for that thorough response. I made the changes you suggested, and it works perfectly. Furthermore, you really made it click in my mind. The integer arrays represent x and y coordinate pairs with an integer counter that represents steps out on the grid from the starting point. I think I see what you mean about creating a class Point to do the comparisons and such. I'm going to work on that right away. Cheers!

Comment: @vitriolik In that case, I suggest that `Point` just include `x` and `y`. The counter should most likely be stored separately.

Answer (score 2):

You have an extra `)` here:

```
element = (int[])it.next()); //with the extra parenthesis the code will not compile
```

should be:

```
element = (int[])it.next();
```

Comment: @Code-Guru I have made the necessary changes in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I would highly recommend to enclose the integer array of 3 numbers into a meaningful class, that would hold, display and control an array of 3 integers.

Then in your main, you can have an growing ArrayList of objects of that class.

Comment: I suggest going a step further by creating a class that clearly describes the meaning of these three `ints`. For example, if they are (x, y, z) coordinates, create a class named `Point` with three member variables named `x`, `y`, and `z`.

Answer (score 1):

Besides the problem in the other answer, you cal it.next() two times, that cause the iterator move forward two times, obviously that's not what you want. The code like this:

```
element = (int[])it.next()); 
String el = (String)element;
```

But actually, I don't see you used el. Although it's legal, it seems meaningless.

Comment: Thanks for that. I should have been clear that I was including both lines just to illustrate what I am probably misunderstanding about how objects can be retrieved from the list.