# Why can't I access elements of 2D ArrayList?

Tags: java, string, arraylist

I have a two dimensional ArrayList that is being populated with string values in a while loop.  The values come from a CSV file that is read using `BufferedReader` and then put into a one dimensional ArrayList using `StringTokenizer`.  The 1D ArrayList is added to the 2D ArrayList in a while loop.

My problem is that I cannot access the elements of the 2D array outside of the while loop.  As you can see from the following code:

```
public String[][] readInCSV(String mg) {


    List<List<String>> twoDim = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
    List<String> row = new ArrayList<String>();
    try {

        BufferedReader CSVFile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\minuteTest.csv"));
        String dataRow="";
        int y=0;

        while ((dataRow = CSVFile.readLine()) != null) {
            StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(dataRow, ",");


            while(st.hasMoreTokens()){

                row.add(st.nextToken());

            }
            System.out.println("row: " + row.get(2));
            twoDim.add(row);
            System.out.println("twoDimTest: " + twoDim.get(y).get(2) + "  y: " + y);
            row.clear();
            y++;
        }

        for(int x=0; x<twoDim.size(); x++){

            System.out.println("twoDim: " + twoDim.get(x).size());
        }
        CSVFile.close();

    } 
    catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
        System.out.println("file not found: " + e1.getMessage());
    } 
    catch (IOException e1) {
        System.out.println("could not read file: " + e1.getMessage());
    }


    return strArray;
}
```

"twoDimTest" prints out exactly what "row" does in the while loop, but "twoDim" prints out 0 in the for loop.  If I try:

```
twoDim.get(0).get(2);
```

it returns an IndexOutOfBoundsExeception.  If I try:

```
twoDim.size();
```

it returns the correct number of rows.

Why are the rows of my 2D array populated in the while loop, but not outside the while loop? 
 How can I access my 2D array outside of the while loop?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ArrayList of integer arrays in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13665188/arraylist-of-integer-arrays-in-java)

Comment: Even though the linked question is about Lists of arrays, rather than a 2D List, the issue is exactly the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your outer list contains many many copies of the same inner list, which you `row.clear();` afterwards.

You need to create a `new ArrayList<>()` for each row, and not clear it.

Comment: Excellent, this worked great.  I did not realize that if I changed the inner list, the changes would be reflected in the outer list, but I guess that makes since since they point to the same memory space...?  Anyways, thanks SLaks

Comment: @dterlip Exactly! You only create one row and add it to the "outer" array list many times.